# c# Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server

Tags: c#

I have already published to the share drive.
I can open the application without a problem.
And I have download the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components.
However a problem saying that the path is not correct for an other computer. Because on other computer, there is no I:\ ,but its call "Computer\"

not sure how I can edit the path below. Thank you.

```
 public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=I:\Fruit\Apple\DataBase\Database4.accdb;
```

Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

Comment: Have you read any of the posts listed under **Related**?

Comment: You don't need full-blown access installed, but you at least need the Data Connectivity Components